# How to fix reading cookie after redirect back?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wrote a simple code that it is redirecting back after I click on button. The redirect is with cookie, but when I read it, it is encrypted, how can I read decrypted value of cookie?

How it works? I have a FrontendController, that includes layout and when I am changing the style it calls through the route /s/dark

The controller Homepage calls Frontend function which is extended, and after this I have to read the cookie, but it is encrypted.

```
function setStyle($style = "light") {
    if($this->cookie->getCookie('style') == "light") {
        $style = "dark";
    } else {
        $style = "light";
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withCookie(cookie('style', $style));
}
```

EDIT

I am expecting **light** value in cookie, but I have got something like this **eyJpdiI6IitEUWc2WDlBT1l3bDcyNW1YbnlcL3RBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlNRQ2ZhcG5INE1iNVwvalZMTjFOZVBRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJmOTFkYTU1ZTY0MTU5NDVhMjQzYWFhZTQxNzdkZGRlZDJkNThhMDU0YTE0YjYwMDU4NzZmYTI2ZTk5ZWIyY2Y1In0=**

Comment: That is because the cookie is `secure`.

Comment: I know that it is secure, but I don't know how to do it without this? I want to secure some cookies and some no...

Comment: Use sessions perhaps?  Or do some front-end javascript and store it in the localStorage.

Comment: I don't want to save it and load it using JavaScript... Is there a solution with Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session instead of a cookie in Laravel.

To store session data:

`$request->session()->put('key', 'value');`

To retrieve session data:

`$value = $request->session()->get('key');`

Say you have a button that says "Switch style to dark" and has the value of 'dark'. When the style is not dark, it says "Switch style to light" and has the value of 'light'. You press the button which takes you to a controller which sets the style in the session:

```
function setStyle(Request $request) 
{
    $style = $request->style;
    $request->session()->put('style', $style);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Now say in the controller when you show your page, you want to display a page as 'light' or 'dark'.

```
public function index()
{
    $style = $request->session()->get('style');

    if ($style == 'light') {
        // do your light thing
        $buttonText = "Switch style to dark";
    } else {
        // do your dark thing
        $buttonText = "Switch style to light";
    }


           // return redirect with style
 }
```

Comment: You will need to set the value first. Where is the function where the user is setting the style as a cookie?

Comment: It is a Controller, when I am setting the style, there is a FrontendController which saves the value of the style. After this it is redirecting to the previous page (HomepageController) and through the controller it is setting through View::share a value from session or cookie.

Comment: In your frontend controller where you set the style, do `$request->session()->put('style', 'dark');` or whichever the style is

Comment: Still doesn't work I tried to put the setStyle and getStyle into one controller (HomeController) and it works, but when you separate it, it doesn't work anyway...

Comment: Dump out the session in your second controller to see what it contains. `dd($request->session()->all());`

Comment: It contains only array brackets without values.